# Function not working correctly

Tags: php, function, mysqli, return

please can someone help me with my code.  I have been at this all day and so close to giving up.

The form displays:
checkfields are not empty
This is expected... 
It continues through the function checkUser() below:

```
    global $mysqli_db;
    global $db_table;
    //Check the field userName is the same as the Posted Username
    $Field = "userName"; //The Field to check
    $query = "SELECT $Field WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck FROM $db_table LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "The result of the checkUser is:<br>";
    echo $result;
    echo "<br>";

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        echo "username was not found in the field in the table<BR>";
        return false; //username was not found in the field in the table
    }
```

The field is the database field within my table $db_table.  I just put it as a variable for simplicity.  I want the next echo to say the result of the checkuser is:
But it does not get that far so I guess I have an error between my $field and $result?
Hope this is clearer, apologies long day.

```
 <?php
//Main Code Sequence
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//Database Setup
$db_host = "***";
$db_name = "***";
$db_table = "emailUser";
$db_username = "***";
$db_password = "***";   
$mysqli_db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);

function webmailSignUp()
{
    global $mysqli_db;
    global $db_table;
    $webmailFullName = $_POST['webmailFullName'];
    $webmailUserName = $_POST['webmailUserName'];
    $webmailExEmail = $_POST['webmailExEmail'];
    $webmailPhone = $_POST['webmailPhone'];
    $webmailDOB = $_POST['webmailDOB'];

    //Check that the fields are not empty
    echo "check";
    if ((empty($webmailFullName)) or (empty($webmailUserName)) or (empty($webmailExEmail)) or (empty($webmailPhone)) or (empty($webmailDOB)))
    {
        echo "One of your fields are blank!  Please try again<BR>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fields are not empty<BR>";
        //Check that there is no existing name in the table
        if (checkUser($webmailUserName) == false)
        {
            echo "Result is <BR>";
            echo checkUser($webmailUserName);
            //Adding the person to the Database Query   
            //$query = "INSERT INTO $db_table(userFullName,userName,userExEmail,userPhone,userDOB) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
            //Binding to Prevent SQL injection                      
            //$requery = $mysqli_db->prepare($query);
            //$requiry->bind_param($webmailFullName,$webmailUserName,$webmailExEmail,$webmailPhone,$webmailDOB);
            //if ($requery->execute())
            //{
            //  echo "Person has been added";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //  echo "bind failed";
            //} 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "There is already a user registered with this username.  Please try a different one.<BR>";
        }
    }
}

function checkUser($userNameCheck)
{
    global $mysqli_db;
    global $db_table;
    //Check the field userName is the same as the Posted Username
    $Field = "userName"; //The Field to check
    $query = "SELECT $Field WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck FROM $db_table LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $query) or die(mysql_error());

    echo "The result of the checkUser is:<br>";
    echo $result;
    echo "<br>";

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()))
    {
        echo "username was not found in the field in the table<BR>";
        return false; //username was not found in the field in the table
    }
    else
    {
        echo "username was found in the field in the table<BR>";
        return true; //username was found in the field in the table
    }
}

function db_close()
{
    global $mysqli_db;
    $mysqli_db->close();
}

if(isset($_POST['webmailRegisterSubmit']))
{
    webmailSignUp();
    db_close();
    echo "End of Registration";
}
if(isset($_POST['webamilForgottenPWSubmit']))
{
    webmailForgottenPassword();
    db_close();
    echo "End of Password Reset Request";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have `$Field = "userName";`? Why don't you just put the actual column name directly into your query instead of making convoluted like this?

Comment: That is the username field in my database.  I have a table called emailUser, and one of the field names is username.  The idea is it looks for the username from the post in the username field to check there is not one already existing

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot the string "checkfields are not empty" in your code...

Comment: @Smokey right, but why put it into a variable? Why don't you put it directly in your query?

Comment: You execute that `checkUser()` function _twice_?!?

Comment: If you have both `webmailRegisterSubmit` and `webamilForgottenPWSubmit` in the same form, then I think both functions are fighting for precedence. What does your form look like?

Comment: check is the first echo, fields are not empty is the second

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if the user is called something like `"1"; DROP TABLE "emailUser"; SELECT * `?

Comment: And this `WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck` should probably have quotes `WHERE $Field='$userNameCheck'`

Comment: This line is incorrect. You have your `FROM` **after your `WHERE`** `"SELECT $Field WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck FROM $db_table LIMIT 1"` which should come first, then you check for `WHERE` --- **Try** `"SELECT $Field FROM $db_table WHERE $Field='$userNameCheck' LIMIT 1"` @Smokey

Comment: So many problems, so little time. I finish work in 30mins and I'm not sure thats enough time to fix this mess :( I beg you to just use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thank you Fred for:   "SELECT $Field FROM $db_table WHERE $Field='$userNameCheck' LIMIT 1";

Comment: You're welcome @Smokey Did that fix it, or is there something else?

Comment: CheckUser() is working, I have removed the commenting in my webMailSignUp() to add a user to the database.  If you could help me out with the global $var and explain what I've done wrong, that would be great.  I thought defining a global variable was ok if used in multiple functions?

Comment: There's a typo `$requiry->bind_param` `if ($requery->execute())` which should be `$requery->bind_param` @Smokey

Comment: Yep just done that one, uploading a test run now

Comment: query binded Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /hermes/bosoraweb033/b1714/ipg.allcolescom/_webmail/mailDB.php on line 45.    I did change INSERT INTO $db_table to INSERT INTO '$db_table'?

Comment: There's nothing (seriously) wrong with global variables (especially if you're using namespaces) but accessing them from within a function using `global $var;` is really very 'old skool' - you'd normally pass any variable you wanted to use inside a function as a parameter: `function foo($bar)`, for what you're doing you'd be far better creating a class and having the variables as class members with accessor and mutator methods for working with them... PHP has become a lot more OOP since version 5 and your code just gave me flashbacks to "the bad old days" (sorry for previous snarky comment)

Comment: Not a problem, I can do setter and getter methods once I get the script functioning, at least database entry.  I didn't realise PHP was like that (first time today), I know a very small amount of Java and keep getting surprised with some of the similarities well like you said Object Orientated nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT $Field FROM $db_table WHERE $Field=$userNameCheck LIMIT 1"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_db, $query) or die(mysql_error());
```

<s>`$userNameCheck` isn't defined and will create a broken query.</s>

`$userNameCheck` isn't correctly enclosed in quotes in your query.

The reason you don't see this is because you are using `mysql_error` despite using `mysqli` for the database queries. Use `mysqli_error` instead.

Comment: Thank you have amended MySQL_error to mysqli_errors.   Please could you explain what the quotes are doing - are they only needed in a MySQLquery string?

Comment: @Smokey The quotes are to let MySQL know that `$userNameCheck` is a string and not a reference to a field. Plus consider what the query would look like if, say, `$userNameCheck` had spaces in it.